# New badges: Riddler and Riddle Solver

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Riddler badge:

Awarded to those who have asked a question with 3 or more points, no (upvoted?) answers in a month and which remains open.

This is not to motivate people to ask unanswerable questions (those will be closed anyway), but is intended to be a compensation for not having your question answered.

Riddle Solver badge:

Awarded to answers to the question who've gotten the Riddler badge and get accepted.

Answer (score 6):

There is already [the Tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed), a consolation for having no answers and low views on your question. But not if you have it upvoted.

On the other end of that is [the Necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) for those who answer a question over 60 days later and garner at least 5 votes.

Comment: Hmm, they are similar but not equal in intent. Although there might be enough overlap between the existing and the proposed to make the latter unworthy of consideration.

Comment: So.. we need a "Tumblemancer" or "Necroweed" badge :D

Comment: Necroweed sounds utterly vicious. Cost much?

Comment: @random - Depends on where you live.